# Sorry I am a beginner. How do I start out with an image being invisible so I can show it using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have 5 images which I simply wish to start out hidden and then show when I click the button I have created.

This is what I have so far. Also sorry I have only been doing this for 4 days.

JQUERY:

```
var main = function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('.bond1').show(1500);
        $('.bond2').show(1500);
        $('.bond3').show(1500);
        $('.bond4').show(1500);
        $('.bond5').show(1500);
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="bond1">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="display:none;">
                    <img hidden src="http://screenfish.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/aconnery.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bond2">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://natenakao.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/lazenby2.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="bond3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img hidden src="http://drop.ndtv.com/Movies/images/articles/big/rogermoorebondbook.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bond4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img hidden src="http://media.irishcentral.com/images/swf+pierce-brosnan-007-james-bond.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="bond5">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img hidden src="http://cdn.hitfix.com/photos/374143/Daniel-Craig-as-James-Bond-in-Quantum-of-Solace._gallery_primary.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first hide them using `$(function(){$('.bond1').hide();})` .. same way other image containers

Comment: sorry man... changed it... but no need to get offended jesus...

Comment: @marc_s You can get your point across without being so harsh. Very rude.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS to set the display of the images to none.

```
.bond1, .bond2, .bond3, .bond4, .bond5 { display: none; }
```

Also, get rid of the hidden attribute on the img tag.

[Working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yckoff8v/)